# How do I make a grid around all my points, and then convert it to a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, polygon, point

I want to make a grid around all my points, convert to a polygon and use this to clip the extent of my data. I am using Arc 10.2.

How do I make a grid and then convert it to a polygon?
Or is there a way to miss some of these steps?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert these points to raster by FeatureToRaster and set cell size to grid width, Then use RasteToPolygon convert raster to grid polygon.